# Was ∆ used in APL as a substitute for space because ECMA-17/ISO 2047 specified △ as graphical representation for space?

Tags: history, text, character-sets, apl, standards

[Wikipedia on naming conventions in programming states](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Naming_convention_(programming)#APL) (without source):

> In APL dialects, the delta (Δ) is used between words, e.g. PERFΔSQUARE (…)

This is an unusual choice, but I notice that [ECMA-17 says](https://www.ecma-international.org/wp-content/uploads/ECMA-17_1st_edition_november_1968.pdf#page=10):

> (…) in certain applications there is a need for a graphical representation of the control characters which are normally non-printing characters.
>
> (…)
>
> | Code position | Character | Pictorial repr. | Alphanumeric repr. |
> | --- | --- | --- | --- |
> | 2/0 | **SPACE** | △ | **SP** |
> | 7/15 | **DELETE** | ▨ | **DT** |

Both the standard and the first modern APL implementation became available in '68, but the standard described existing usage, and it would make sense to use an existing substitute character for internal "spaces" in names, since space and juxtaposition has syntactic significance in APL.

**Is there any indication that APL's usage of `∆` for separating words in identifiers originates in common usage as a control picture for space? Alternatively, is there any indication of another origin of APL's unusual choice?**

Comment: Now that's interesting. Didn't know about ECMA-17, but remember next to all of them (sans NIL and SPACE) from several early terminal (vector based) of that time.

Comment: Eons ago, one of my college lecturers used to write small triangles underneath a line to indicate spaces when he wrote Fortran code on paper or a black/white board. I think I have seen this used in some computer language books of the era. Other books from that era used to use a lower case b with a slash through it to indicate spaces in a computer program. Using triangles this way is something I picked up then & still occasionally use.

Comment: The first manuals I read used a delta symbol for space, though I recall it as 'upside down delta'.  Slashed-out lower-case 'b' I remember as an IBM-manual thing.  Conversely, I do not recall that particular use of delta in APL.

Comment: When taking notes where I need a space to stand out, I still use IBM's old convention for a hand-written space, which is an underscore with little downticks on the end.  The delta notation is cool though.

Comment: @WayneConrad - downticks (`⎴`) or upticks (`⎵`)? (huh, the unicode "TOP SQUARE BRACKET" (shown first) is at the "top" of the character box, there's apparently no similar character to the "BOTTOM SQUARE BRACKET" at the _bottom_ but with the ticks going down ...)  (I've always used the one at the bottom with the ticks going up, and I'm finding this question interesting because though I used the delta as a "word separator" in APL identifiers I never knew it had a more general meaning.)

Comment: @davidbak I use downticks as shown in "TOP SQUARE BRACKET" , but unlike the unicode character, my horizontal line is lowered as it is in "BOTTOM SQUARE BRACKET".  But it's possible I've misremembered the IBM standard, and it's supposed to be upticks when I'm filling out my COBOL coding form.

Comment: @WayneConrad I do as well only remember 'upticks' for space tepresentation wenn needed.

Comment: The first manual that came to hand was a University of Essex 'A.S.A. FORTRAN mini-manual' dated 1973.  This uses "upside-down delta", whose name I now recall is 'nabla', mostly in discussions of the relationship between FORMAT and what's on the external media.  Contraiwise, the IBM FORTRAN II General Information  Manual just uses lower-case 'b' for a similar purpose (obviously no conflict with anything a computer could print :-))

Comment: For what it's worth, GNU APL [says](https://www.gnu.org/software/apl/apl-intro.html#CH_3.2.1) that Δ is used to offset a common prefix from a group of related names, i.e., pretty much the way VMS used $ (SYS$THIS, LIB$THAT, etc.)  I find that more plausible than regarding it as primarily a connective between words.

Comment: ECMA 17 is basically a re-publication of ISO 2047, which wasn't published until 1975. While my memory that far back is frail at best, I *think* use of delta in APL was fairly well established by then. If anything, I'd suggest that that situation may be the reverse of what's suggested here: that ISO 2047/ECMA-17 adopted the practice from APL.

Comment: @JerryCoffin How do you explain the *This Standard ECMA—17 has been adopted by the General Assembly of November 28, 1968.* on page 4 of the linked doc?

Answer (score 6):

Some observations, not an entire answer.

In APL\360, only upper case letters, underlined upper case letters, and digits were allowed in user-defined names.

(There were a couple of exceptions: TΔ*function* and SΔ*function*, for program control, as pointed out by @Adam in comments. This does not seem to imply general use of delta in names)

By the time of [APL2 (page 12)](https://bitsavers.org/pdf/ibm/apl/SH20-9229-1_An_Introduction_to_APL_2_Dec85.pdf) delta and underlined delta have been added, along with underscore and the negative symbol, and possibly lower case letters.

The presence of both underscore and delta suggest to me that this wasn't the 'unusual choice' of the OP's wording, since the usual choice -- underscore -- is catered for.  That doesn't give the reason **for** including delta, but (opinion) I am inclined to not believe that its due to its use as a conventional space indication.

Indeed, the use of delta in actual programs seems contrary to its use of a conventional space mark.  For all other space indications, we're supposed to understand that the mark in the manual is **not** what you see on the equipment.

Lastly, nothing in the linked APL2 manual suggests that delta is intended as a separator; it's just a valid character in names, of equal standing with the 'normal' letters.  You can start a name with delta, or even use it as a name by itself.

Comment: Note that in APL\360, `S∆MYPROGRAM` and `T∆MYPROGRAM` were used for **S**top and **T**race control of `MYPROGRAM`.

Comment: @Adam - Are those system commands or did they appear in programs?

Comment: They were just special variables, so they could appear in programs.

Comment: @Adam - is there a manual in which they appear?  I didn't find a mention. Thanks.

Comment: Yes: [trace control](https://www.softwarepreservation.org/projects/apl/Books/196808_APL360%20Users%20Manual.pdf#page=72) and [stop control](https://www.softwarepreservation.org/projects/apl/Books/196808_APL360%20Users%20Manual.pdf#page=77).

Comment: In that context, it seems less like a character in a name and more like a strange sort of operator (yielding an l-value).  But maybe it's best to regard it as a character that can only be used in system-defined names, maybe like the &variables of SNOBOL4; e.g. to anchor pattern matching you assign non-zero to the system variable named &anchor.